# Creating EC2 instance profile as part of the IAM role for EMR in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-emr

In Terraform, we can create a custom EC2 role (emr-role-001) and we can create an instance profile that references that role. However, if we create it this way, EMR won't accept this instance profile. Instead, it has to be the instance profile created automatically when the custom EC2 role (emr-role-001) is created.

How can I do this in Terraform? Below is a sample of the code I am using.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_emr_profile_role" {
  name = "iam_emr_profile_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "emr_profile" {
  name = "emr_profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.iam_emr_profile_role.name
}
```

The error is that the instance profile is not valid, whenever I try to use it when deploying the EMR cluster.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using as well as the error if any?

Comment: @MarkoE added the code. The error is that the instance profile is not valid to use in EMR.

Comment: I see in the documentation that there are `ec2_attributes` and `service_role`. Can you also add the part of code where the IAM policy is defined for the service role and the EMR code?

Comment: Btw, I would try changing the policy version to `2012-10-17`.